# Saving User Preferences

Tags: activities, user-experience

Does anyone know how I can turn off this improvement?

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-11761

> Save user preferences for filtering Activities tab listings
>
> The requirement is to persist the last used values for the two activity type filters on the contact Activities tab => "Filter by Activity Type" form (activity_type_filter_id and activity_type_exclude_filter_id) for the logged in user.
>
> The filter values would need to be saved onChange since there is no search form POST, and loaded from the DB when that tab is accessed.

It's causing a lot of problems for users

Comment: I agree this seems like something that should be an option in settings. I expect this will require funding and perhaps an issue should be opened in JIRA referencing the old ticket so that it can be discussed there. Also you may want to just ask this question no JIRA ... oh never mind. i did so on your behalf. hope that was okay. guessing you may not have or want a JIRA account.

Answer (score 1):

Up until now the answer has been no. However this improvement is now available with the PR from this [JIRA issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20799).

Comment: I think we can take on adding a setting for that option.

Comment: Here's the pull request (note that it also implements two new filters on the activity tab): https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10588

Comment: cool. updated answer to reflect this new info